# Converting Row into list RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list in form

```
[Row(_1=u'5', _2=u'6')]
```

I want to convert it into

```
[(5,6)]
```

using PySpark

Comment: Is this is an RDD or a list? I suspect it's just a list, so you don't need Pyspark here, rather just the normal Python. Something like `[x[0] for x in <your_list>]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your *[Row(_1=u'5', _2=u'6')]* is a line in your rdd:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

a = [Row(_1=u'5', _2=u'6')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(a) 
print rdd.take(1)
# >>> [Row(_1=u'5', _2=u'6')]

b = rdd.map(lambda line: tuple([int(x) for x in line]))
print b.take(3)
# >>> [(5, 6)]
```

Comment: But I see no guarantees on the sequence of the list. So I assumed the content is a Row is a dict-like. How do you guarantee the order of the content extracted from a Row? thanks

Comment: Ok, From the code of pyspark, we know the Row is a sub-class of Python tuple. So orders inside a Row is guaranteed here. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#Row

Answer (score 3):

`Row` is a tuple, so all you need is:

```
rdd.map(tuple)
```

to get `RDD[tuple]` or

```
rdd.map(list)
```

to get `RDD[list]`.

Comment: I add the source code link here for you to make sure that the Row is actually sub-class of tuple of Python. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#Row